# Sphinx relative reference to internal html file

Tags: python-sphinx, pdflatex

I have a larger documentation, which I create with sphinx. For the C++ code, I use breathe extension to include the doxygen information from the code.
There is an API chapter with the whole content of the header. I want to refer to the APIs within my documentation with a link and not include the full description
For the html it works well with

```
`API link <../myAPI/myAPI.html#_CPPv426myLink>`_
```

but with latexpdf it's not working. There i got the link with

```
`API link <abolute_path/myAPI/myAPI.html#_CPPv426myLink>`_
```

but i want a link within the pdf

How i can solve this problem for the pdf